# ffmpeg always passes the video through directshow?

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, flash-media-server, flashmedialiveencoder

ffmpeg always passes the video through directshow?

I need to get a streaming video that came from a ip camera, and pass it to directshow. I'm using ffmpeg to get this video, and I'd like know if on windows,  everything that ffmpeg makes use the directshow?

Iknow how can I get a movie in rstp protocol, but I don't know how can I output it to directshow.

If true how can I get a movie, read it and pass the output to directshow?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should try to provide more details on what you are trying to achieve and what you have done already (and how you did it)

Comment: how are you getting the video with ffmpeg?  what type of output do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg is a self-contained compression/decompression tool/library, it does not use directshow by default, however [you can configure it](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC26) so that it uses directshow (via avisynth), and it can also be used with directshow-based applications, ([ffdshow filter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow/)).

In order to capture a rtsp stream using directshow I would suggest to use a rtsp source filter, you can find one [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtspdirectshow).

For further understanding of the whole process I would suggest following a few [directshow tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077997/where-can-i-find-a-thorough-directshow-tutorial) as a preliminary step.

Edit:

According to comments, it seems to me that you need a directshow source filter that can be used inside Flash Media Encoder. I do not know about any (free)filter for this, but there are comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376734/fake-directshow-video-capture-device) and [here](http://rafaelspereira.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/publishing-rtsp-streams-on-fms-how/) about how to deal this problem.

Comment: Can I configure the output to directshow making the reverse of 
"ffmpeg -i input.avs" ? ie, passing the streaming output to an *.avs file?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean with "output to directshow...". You can use directshow as input since the output will always be an uncompressed stream, you can then use this stream and display it, or recompress it into another format. However, using directshow as output, I cannot figure out what that would be.

Comment: As I mentioned before, giving more details on what your original goal is will help everone to understand your problem and provide more accurated assistence.

Comment: ok, I need to get the rtsp streaming and pass it to flash media live encoder, to send in correct format to akamai, and flash media live encoder works only with content that pass to directshow. My idea is get the streaming with ffmpeg and send to directshow, but I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: It can also accept direct dshow input these days: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/08/ffmpeg-directshow/